# Правильная строка в параметре $_GET

Tags: php

Предедаю get параметр

```
&key2=от_90_000_тенге_+_дизайн.
```

Потом вывожу через `echo`

```
echo $_GET['key2'];
```

Но знак `+` пропадает? как правильно передает что бы символ `+` остался?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671840/php-plus-sign-with-get-query

Comment: [Знак `+` зарезервирован](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). Используйте `%2B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

формируя строку параметров:

```
query_string = "key2=" . urlencode("от_90_000_тенге_+_дизайн");
```

принимая параметр:

```
urldecode($_GET['key2']);
```